# Is StackExchange.Redis client restricted when subscribed to a channel?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I want to use StackExchange.Redis to develop a PUB/SUB message queue.

In StackExchange.Redis documentation it is specified that:

> -The data is not sent via pub/sub; the pub/sub API is only used to notify workers to check for more work

So I understand that I may need to use other redis operations like LPOP to check for work once a subscribed worker detects a notification via PUB/SUB.

However Redis reference specifies:

> Once the client enters the subscribed state it is not supposed to
>   issue any other commands, except for additional SUBSCRIBE, PSUBSCRIBE,
>   UNSUBSCRIBE and PUNSUBSCRIBE commands.

With StackExchange.Redis am I supposed to create another Multiplexer in my subscribe handler to issue commands like LPOP?

Is it possible to share the same multiplexer for both Subscribe and other commands?

Should my worker unsubscribe when it receives a notification to check for work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use a shared multiplexer?

No there is absolutely no issue in using only one ConnectionMultiplexer and subscribe to as many things you want and do other stuff with it, as the Stackexchange.Redis client does all the stuff behind the scenes for you. It does actually handle a new connection for the subscriber internally.

Meaning, no, you don't have to create a new Multiplexer every time, and no, you don't have to issue any other commands to use the subscriber.

Just create a new subscriber

```
ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();
```

then subscribe to whatever you want

```
sub.Subscribe("messages", (channel, message) => {
    Console.WriteLine((string)message);
});
```

or send messages

```
sub.Publish("messages", "hello");
```

As explained also in [Marc's docs](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md#using-redis-pubsub)

Comment: I understand that I can subscribe to multiple channels with only one Multiplexer, but what if instead of a Console.WriteLine in the handler I want to do other Redis operations using the same ConnectionMultiplexer? Redis docs state that I should not do that since a client in a subscribed state should not issue more commands. Is StackExchange.Redis exempt from this restriction?

Comment: Did I not answer that clearly enough?  You can use one mulitplexer for everything, yes. You don't have to create another one...
Did you even try it at all so far?